# Search a JSON array for an object containing a value matching a pattern

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a DB with a `jsonb` column where each row essentially holds an array of name value pairs. Example for a single `jsonb` value:

```
[
    {"name":"foo", "value":"bar"},
    {"name":"biz", "value":"baz"},
    {"name":"beep", "value":"boop"}
]
```

How would I query for rows that contain a partial value? I.e., find rows with the JSON object key `value` ilike '%ba%'?

I know that I can use `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE jsoncol @> '[{"value":"bar"}]'` to find rows where the JSON is that specific value, but how would I query for rows containing a pattern?

Answer (score 4):

#### Postgres 12 or newer

Use an [SQL/JSON path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH), where you can test with [`like_regex`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  t.jsoncol @? '$[*].value ? (@ like_regex "ba" flag "i")';
```

Only add `flag "i"` for case insensitive matching.

Can an index. See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)

#### Postgres 11 or older

There are no built in [`jsonb` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) nor any indexes supporting this kind of filter directly (yet).

I suggest an `EXISTS` semi-join:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.jsoncol) elem
   WHERE  elem->>'value' LIKE '%ba%'
   );
```

It avoids redundant evaluations and the final `DISTINCT` step you would need to get distinct rows with a plain `CROSS JOIN`.

If this still isn't fast enough, a way more sophisticated specialized solution for the given type of query would be to extract a concatenated string of unique values (with a delimiter that won't interfere with your search patterns) per row in an `IMMUTABLE` function, build a trigram GIN index on the functional expression and use the same expression in your queries.

Related:

- [Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202761/3684)
- [Create Postgres JSONB Index on Array Sub-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822254/create-postgres-jsonb-index-on-array-sub-object/47825641#47825641)

Aside, if your `jsonb` values really look like the example, you could trim a lot of noise and just store:

```
[
   {"foo":"bar"},
   {"biz":"baz"},
   {"beep":"boop"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in a lateral join and use its result `value` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select distinct t.* 
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(jsoncol)
where value->>'value' like '%ba%'
```

Please, read [How to query jsonb arrays with IN operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816105/1995738) for notes about `distinct` and performance.