# LIKE query on elements of flat jsonb array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a Postgres table `posts` with a column of type `jsonb` which is basically a flat array of tags.

What i need to do is to somehow run a LIKE query on that `tags` column elements so that i can find a posts which has a tags beginning with some partial string.

Is such thing possible in Postgres? I'm constantly finding super complex examples and no one is ever describing such basic and simple scenario.

My current code works fine for checking if there are posts having specific tags:

```
select * from posts where tags @> '"TAG"'
```

and I'm looking for a way of running something among the lines of

```
select * from posts where tags @> '"%TAG%"'
```

Comment: have you considerd something like `select * from posts where wmi_codes::text LIKE '%TAG%'`?

Comment: i did and that's my plan B but it kind of feels like i'm dropping all the pros of using jsonb column with this solution instead of storing it just as a text column...am i ?

Comment: I totally agree with you, it's not elegant at all. It does feel strange to use such an approach, but if it does what you want and there is no performance implication, I would still consider it. Good luck :-)

Comment: If you want to process data efficiently in PostgreSQL, don't store them as JSON. If it is a list of tags, store them in a table. Then everything will become simple.

Comment: i kind of need to use jsonb, that was not my decision nor my code and i need to adapt :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   posts p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(p.tags) tag
   WHERE  tag LIKE '%TAG%'
   );
```

Related, with explanation:

- [Search a JSON array for an object containing a value matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824466/search-a-json-array-for-an-object-containing-a-value-matching-a-pattern/49826693#49826693)

Or simpler with the [**`@?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) since Postgres 12 implemented SQL/JSON:

```sql
SELECT *
--     optional to show the matching item:
--   , jsonb_path_query_first(tags, '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "^ tag" flag "i")')
FROM   posts
WHERE  tags @? '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "TAG")';
```

The operator `@?` is just a wrapper around the [function `jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). So this is equivalent:

```sql
...
WHERE  jsonb_path_exists(tags, '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "TAG")');
```

Neither has index support. (May be added for the `@?` operator later, but not there in pg 13, yet). So those queries are slow for big tables. A normalized design, [like Laurenz already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101530/like-query-on-jsonb-flat-array-column#comment87219977_50101530) would be superior - with a trigram index:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

For just **prefix matching** (`LIKE 'TAG%'`, no leading wildcard), you could make it work with a **full text index**:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_tags_fts_gin_idx ON posts USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', tags));
```

And a matching query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts p
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', tags)  @@ 'TAG:*'::tsquery
```

Or use the `english` dictionary instead of `simple` (or whatever fits your case) if you want stemming for natural English language.

[`to_tsvector(json(b))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) requires **Postgres 10** or later.

Related:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: @IljaEverilä: Yes, Postgres 12 made that possible. I added something above.