# SqlAlchemy: query to find json items that begin with a substring inside an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a complex json object saved on a postgresql database and I want to find all entries that contain or begin with a substring inside an array. The json object:

```
    "configurations" : {
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "nodes" : [ {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:apache:http_server:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
      "versionStartIncluding" : "2.4.0",
      "versionEndIncluding" : "2.4.41"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

More specifically, I want to find all objects that begin with : "cpe:2.3:a:apache" in the "cpe23Uri" field.

Query I have made:

```
session.query(cvemodel.data['configurations']['nodes'][0]['cpe_match'].contains([{'cpe23Uri': 'cpe:2.3:a:apache:http_server:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*'}])).all()
```

Problem with this query is that, it matches the whole word. If I put this:

```
session.query(cvemodel.data['configurations']['nodes'][0]['cpe_match'].contains([{'cpe23Uri': 'cpe:2.3:a:apache:http_server'}])).first()
```

It does not return anything!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL 12 or later, you can use [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) and friends:

```
needle = 'cpe:2.3:a:apache:http_server'

session.query(cvemodel).\
    filter(func.jsonb_path_exists(
        cvemodel.data,
        '''$.configurations.nodes[0].cpe_match[*].cpe23Uri ?
           (@ starts with $needle)''',
        json.dumps({"needle": needle}))).\
    all()
```

If you want to check if `cpe23Uri` contains the needle, you can use the `like_regex` predicate, especially if you have a static "needle"; unfortunately `like_regex` only accepts string literals as right operand. Another option for a "contains" query would be to extract the `cpe23Uri` using either `jsonb_path_query()`, or accessors and `jsonb_array_elements()`, and use traditional `LIKE`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101530/like-query-on-elements-of-flat-jsonb-array/50111177#50111177).