# How do I exclude from array in postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I want to change the condition on the array column `call_type` in below query so it excludes everything that has 'visit_occurred'.
How do I work with that array part?

```
select staff_id,
   COUNT(event_id) as offered
from call_logs as logs
where visit_offered
and contact_date between now() - interval '1 weeks' and now()
and provider_type = 'Contractor'
and contact_with != 'company_staff'
and direction = 'outbound'
and outcome = 'Successful'
and call_type && array  ['Schedule','schedule_visit']
group by staff_id;
```

Comment: *"excludes everything that has 'visit_occurred'"* is a bit fuzzy. Do you want to match array elements *exactly* or identify elements that *contain* the given string? And please *always* disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

To simply **match array elements as a whole** use the [ARRAY contains operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), negated:

```
AND  NOT call_type @> '{schedule_visit}'::text[]
```

Note the array wrapper. The cast to `text[]` is typically not needed, but can help to avoid ambiguity.

If the column can be `NULL`, and you don't want to exclude such rows:

```
AND  (call_type @> '{schedule_visit}'::text[]) IS NOT TRUE
```

Can be supported with an index:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

**Pattern matching** is more sophisticated. Use a `NOT EXISTS` expression:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM unnest(logs.call_type) call
   WHERE  call ILIKE '%visit_occurred%'  -- case insensitive?
   )
```

No index support for this. Related answer for a JSON array (same principle):

- [Search a JSON array for an object containing a value matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824466/search-a-json-array-for-an-object-containing-a-value-matching-a-pattern/49826693#49826693)

An alternative would be normalizing your array column as a separate n:1 table.